# Jenkins Dashboard view to show multiple Cucumber Reports

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm

**Background**: we have like ~50 Jenkins jobs (and more to come) executing Cucumber scenarios and generating and posting reports using [Cucumber Reports Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin).

**Problem:** Cucumber reports can be inspected only one by one; I mean, we have to go through all the jobs and to check the relevant reports.

**Question:** Is there an already **existing** solution to create a Jenkins Dashboard View and to *put* there all the reports (column view, matrix view, whatever)? I tried [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) plugin, but does not support Cucumber reports. [Radiator View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) did not fix my problem either. I would like to have a single dashboard view and to see all the Cucumber reports for the added test execution jobs.

Comment: Are you running this in the cloud/supported fixed hardware/inhouse fixed hardware? Also what language are you using for your tests themselves? JRuby or pure JAVA/JVM?

Comment: Inhouse fixed hardware, local instance of Jenkins and Jenkins2. All the projects are maven, written in Java using Cucumber JVM + Selenium WebDriver + REST Assured and other related testing frameworks.

Comment: Ah, damn. In Ruby there is a gem, https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder , that allows you to post all your reports into one folder and then concatenate them into one. It would be interesting to see if there is a solution for JAVA. Essentially it would be to store all the JSON results in a central store and then run a task at the end of the last task to build an HTML report from those.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could not find anything. I solved it by writing a simple app that combed the cucumber-reports directories and read the cucumber-trends.json files.

I then output this to an html page that I landed in userContent.

Whole process took about a day, less time than I spent looking for a pre-made solution...